# Standard_in error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have two bash scripts that are almost identical.  One works and one doesn't and I can't figure out what's going on.  Here are the scripts:

This one works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDIR=$HOME/Documents/Development/road/Earthmoving
TOL=0.05

echo -e "\nRunning Unit Tests"
echo -e "------------------\n"

for infile in $CURDIR/utest/*.csv
do
    file=$(basename $infile .csv)
    echo -n " Test $file"
    value=`$CURDIR/Release/earthmove -f $infile`
    res=`cat $CURDIR/utest/$file.res`
    if [ "$(echo "$res+$TOL*$res >= $value && $res-$TOL*$res <= $value" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo -e "\t\t PASSED."
    else
    echo -e "\t\t FAILED."
    fi;
done

echo ""
```

But this one gives me all kinds of errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDIR=$HOME/Documents/Development/road/Vertical
TOL=0.05

echo -e "\nRunning Unit Tests"
echo -e "------------------\n"

for infile in $CURDIR/utest/*.csv
do
    file=$(basename $infile .csv)
    echo -n " Test $file"
    value=`$CURDIR/Release/vertical -f $infile`
    res=`cat $CURDIR/utest/$file.res`
    if [ "$(echo "$res+$TOL*$res >= $value && $res-$TOL*$res <= $value" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo -e "\t\t PASSED."
    else
    echo -e "\t\t FAILED."
    fi;
done

echo ""
```

The two files are IDENTICAL besides the directory (Earthmoving vs Vertical) and the program name (earthmove vs vertical).  I know this because I created the second by copying and pasting the first.  Running the second script results in this:

```
Running Unit Tests
------------------

 Test flatroad(standard_in) 1: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: N
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: O
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 3: syntax error
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: H
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 3: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 4: syntax error
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: H
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 4: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 5: syntax error
(standard_in) 5: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 6: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 6: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 6: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 6: syntax error
(standard_in) 6: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 7: syntax error
(standard_in) 7: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 8: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 8: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 8: syntax error
(standard_in) 8: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 8: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 15: syntax error
(standard_in) 16: syntax error
(standard_in) 16: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 16: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 16: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 17: syntax error
(standard_in) 18: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 18: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 18: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 18: syntax error
(standard_in) 19: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 19: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 19: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 19: syntax error
(standard_in) 20: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 20: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 20: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 20: syntax error
(standard_in) 21: illegal character: T
.
.
.
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: O
(standard_in) 90: syntax error
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: P
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 90: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 91: syntax error
(standard_in) 91: syntax error
(standard_in) 91: syntax error
(standard_in) 91: syntax error
(standard_in) 93: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 93: syntax error
(standard_in) 94: illegal character: O
(standard_in) 94: syntax error
(standard_in) 95: syntax error
(standard_in) 96: illegal character: U
(standard_in) 96: syntax error
(standard_in) 96: illegal character: '
(standard_in) 96: illegal character: O
(standard_in) 96: illegal character: '
                 FAILED.
```

There are plenty more lines where the "..." is, but they're basically just a variation on the same idea.

Comment: what's `vertical`? what's `earthmove`?

Comment: Are you able to run `$CURDIR/Release/vertical` on its own, with the `flatroad` file? Does that produce all the same errors?

Comment: vertical and earthmove are two c++ programs.  And yes, running "vertical -f flatroad.csv" from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 12):

The error messages are produced by `bc`. The problem is that there is something like "S:S:N:I::O:P..." in the file "$HOME/Documents/Development/road/Vertical/utest/$file.res" that's not in the corresponding file that's used in the other script. Chances are that you expect that file to contain a single numeric value instead of whatever is in there now.

Comment: flatroad.res (the only .res file in the directory at this time) contains only "0.0" (minus the quotes) which IS a single numeric value.

Comment: @Jessica: Then the value of `$value` contains something that `bc` doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the Vertical directory. Does one of your CSV files have spaces or odd characters in its name? Try surrounding the variable that holds a file name in quotes:

```
"\"${filename}\""
```

Comment: The only files that are currently in in Vertical/utest are flatroad.csv and flatroad.res.

I tried your suggestion, and in addition to all the other errors, I now also get the following:

"Test flatroad.csv"cat: /home/jessica/Documents/Development/road/Vertical/utest/flatroad.csv".res: No such file or directory"

Comment: What files are in /home/jessica/Documents/Development/road/Vertical/utest ?

Also try turning on verbose mode in bash:

$ set -v

You can turn it off with "set +v"

Answer (score 0):

> (standard_in) 1: syntax error

This error will be solved by using **perl** instead of bc command,

**$(perl -e "print $b+$c")**